# Why bitfields store negative number even after assigning a positive value?

Tags: c++, unsigned, signed, bit-fields

In the following code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct abc{
    int x:4;
} m;
int main(){
    m.x = 8;
    cout<<m.x;  
}
```

Here the variable x is signed and I assigned it a value of 8 but the output is coming out to be -8. If I change the declaration of int x:4 by unsigned int x:4 then the output is correct. Why the output in first case comes out to be -8 even though I assigned x a positive value? Please explain in detail. And also how are signed and unsigned variables stored in memory?

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of integral overflow. A bitfield of 4 bits of signed type can represent 16 distinct values, integers -8 through 7 (assuming the typical 2's complement representation).

Comment: 8 doesn't fit in a signed 4-bit integer.

Comment: Negative zero is always a fun concept.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks I got it. When I enter 8, it exceeds the limit and jumps back to its lowest value which is -8 and if I enter 9 it jumps back to -7. Thanks I got it now.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: The behavior is *implementation-defined*, not undefined. Overflow on integer assignment has always been implementation-defined in C++. Integer overflow leads to undefined behavior in arithmetic, but not in assignment or conversions.